# Proposed list of tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I noticed that nobody has enough rep or + votes to make synonyms, so I'd like to collect them here for when the time comes that we can create them.

Comment: @Dori: Aha! I was wondering why I could do that despite the rep level :-) May I ask you for a link to what other special behaviour is active during beta?

Answer (score 1):

[anything-in-multiples](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anything-in-multiples) -> [singular](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singular) except for [twins](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twins) and [multiplets](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplets).

There are so many instances already of singular vs. multiple that I think nearly every tag should have it's multiple as synonym, with very very few exceptions. I fear this could be overwhelming to manage. I wonder how other sites handle this?

Answer (score 0):

[toddlers](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddlers) -> [toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddler)

[cot](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cot) -> [crib](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crib) (or vice versa?)